# Finding height from two elevation angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> The top of a hill from the top and bottom of a building of height h is at angles of elevation p and q. What is height of the hill?
>
> (a) $h\cdot \frac {\cot q}{\cot q-\cot p}$
>
> (b) $h\cdot \frac {\cot p}{\cot p-\cot q}$
>
> (c) $2h\cdot \frac {\tan p}{\tan p-\tan q}$
>
> (d) $2h\cdot \frac {\tan q}{\tan q-\tan p}$

i have tried using the formula of $\tan x = \frac {perpendicular}{base}$ but couldn't reach the equation.

Comment: please answer!!

Comment: please check that the options are correct - in particular the factor of $2$ in c) and d)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the height of the hill (relative to the base of the building) as $H$, and the distance to the hill as $d$,

$$\tan q=\frac {H}d$$

$$\tan p=\frac {H-h}d$$

so
$$\tan q - \tan p =\frac {h}d$$

...can you complete to find $H$ from here?